# Изменение размера изображения

Tags: objective-c, ios

Как нарисовать изображение UIImage, увеличенное в N раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так:

```
CGFloat factor = 2.5;   // во сколько раз изменяем размер
CGSize targetSize = CGSizeMake(image.size.width * factor, image.size.height * factor);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);
float x = (targetSize.width - image.size.width * factor) / 2;
float y = (targetSize.height - image.size.height * factor) / 2;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, y, image.size.width * factor, image.size.height * factor);
[image drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return result;
```

Answer (score 1):

Должно помочь:

```
//  ==============================================================
//  resizedImage
//  ==============================================================
// Return a scaled down copy of the image.

UIImage* resizedImage(UIImage *inImage, CGRect thumbRect)
{
    CGImageRef          imageRef = [inImage CGImage];
    CGImageAlphaInfo    alphaInfo = CGImageGetAlphaInfo(imageRef);

    // There's a wierdness with kCGImageAlphaNone and CGBitmapContextCreate
    // see Supported Pixel Formats in the Quartz 2D Programming Guide
    // Creating a Bitmap Graphics Context section
    // only RGB 8 bit images with alpha of kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst, kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst,
    // and kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast, with a few other oddball image kinds are supported
    // The images on input here are likely to be png or jpeg files
    if (alphaInfo == kCGImageAlphaNone)
        alphaInfo = kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast;

    // Build a bitmap context that's the size of the thumbRect
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(
                NULL,
                thumbRect.size.width,       // width
                thumbRect.size.height,      // height
                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),   // really needs to always be 8
                4 * thumbRect.size.width,   // rowbytes
                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                alphaInfo
        );

    // Draw into the context, this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, thumbRect, imageRef);

    // Get an image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef  ref = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage*    result = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:ref];

    CGContextRelease(bitmap);   // ok if NULL
    CGImageRelease(ref);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: а что передается в thumbRect? те, размеры, которые должны получиться? но с width/height более менее все понятно... а в x и y тогда что? 0,0?

Comment: да в thumbRect нужный размер изображения. x,y - координаты левого верхнего угла, в данном случае попробуйте 0,0.

Comment: как ни крути ничего не выводит... мб дело в том, что изображения не в палитре 256 цветов